# Server-side templates not displaying fields in embedded signing experience

Tags: docusignapi

This is complicated but I'll try to explain. I've written an API integration in PHP. With this module installed on my website, I'm able to call a web service (on my website), pass it a PDF, and a collection of requisite parameters including a specific template ID in my Docusign account, and get back an embedded signing link, which I can then use to redirect to the Docusign signing experience for that template/document combination.

The PDF document I'm passing is the exact same PDF in the selected template, but with data filled into some of the files, whereas the version in the template is blank. In the template, various fields are defined (signature tab, date signed, SSN, etc..). These are clearly visible and correctly configured. One can verify this by going into the account and editing the template in question from the Docusign web UI.

My problem is that of the 5 templates I have configured, only one is working as expected (PDF shows up, you fill in the fields and sign, and click "Finish"... callback web hook fires delivering the finished PDF back to my server... done.). The rest show none of the configured fields signers are supposed to interact with. You can click continue, but in the left sidebar, you get the tools for adding fields to the document, instead of the pre-configured ones displaying properly in the body of the PDF.

The template that's working, was broken two days ago with the symptoms described above. I've done nothing to the account or that template and it's magically working somehow. I called tech support on Friday and they told me that occasionally templates get corrupted on the docusign server, but that was tier 1 support and I'm not sure that's a valid comment.

That's about the best I can do to describe the problem. I'm unsure what specific information I could supply to help troubleshoot this, but I'll watch the thread and react as quickly as possible.

I'm observing the exact same behavior in both dev and live environments with the exact same group of templates. The one that works in the live environment is the same one that works in dev.

**List of templates:** (this is for the Dev implementation)

- 86841739-f12d-460e-9807-23a9b90cff6b (only this one works)
- 6c3fd328-6f2e-4de1-a9bc-f50df7761ec2
- 68ce0c9e-a892-4a15-b0f5-39f28aba4588
- cd4e3b6d-a8ea-4c78-a0f8-602753996743
- 9278c78b-f703-429a-ac62-9361bd02f54a

The above represents the 5 templates I'm testing. Only the first one works as expected. I'll add the json later this evening, as I'm out of time at the moment.

Here's the json for each of the templates (zip file):

- https://ufile.io/quo3j

Comment: Can you please share your template Json and the envelope creation Json. Also please add  your template id's to the question.

Comment: The recipient role name in your first template is `NewHire`. The other templates have a roleName of `Employee`. Are you matching the correct roleNames with your template during envelope creation. Can you please share your envelope creation json.

Comment: Problem solved. See my answer below. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was indeed a discrepancy between the roleName of the template and that passed to the API during envelope creation. They must be the same. If you use a template with a different roleName than the one you pass when creating an envelope, you will get the exact behavior I've described.

The solution is to edit your templates on the Docusign website, and use the same roleName for them all, then make sure that's what you're passing the API when creating envelopes.